# Can't display data captured through Json in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

```
        $.getJSON("https://example.com//json/", function (data) {
        var count = Object.keys(data).length;
          for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              var lat = data[i].LAT;
              var lng = data[i].LNG;
              var locs = { lat: lat, lng: lng };
              var check = arePointsNear(pos, locs, 2487);
              if (check) listStations.push(data[i].ID); 
          }
          console.log(listStations);
          console.log(listStations[0]);
        }); 

        function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, m) { 
           var km = m/1000;
           var ky = 40000 / 360;
           var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180) * ky;
           var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
           var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
           return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
        }
```

Example json in data;

```
{
    "ID": 359,
    "NAME": "Atatürk Bulvarı 1",
    "LOCATION": "0001 Atatürk Bulvarı 1",
    "PARK_INFO": "2",
    "PARK_CAPACITY": 18,
    "START_TIME": {
      "Ticks": 270000000000,
      "Days": 0,
      "Hours": 7,
      "Milliseconds": 0,
      "Minutes": 30,
      "Seconds": 0,
      "TotalDays": 0.3125,
      "TotalHours": 7.5,
      "TotalMilliseconds": 27000000,
      "TotalMinutes": 450,
      "TotalSeconds": 27000
    },
    "FINISH_TIME": {
      "Ticks": 666000000000,
      "Days": 0,
      "Hours": 18,
      "Milliseconds": 0,
      "Minutes": 30,
      "Seconds": 0,
      "TotalDays": 0.77083333333333326,
      "TotalHours": 18.5,
      "TotalMilliseconds": 66600000,
      "TotalMinutes": 1110,
      "TotalSeconds": 66600
    },
    "DISTRICT_CODE": "20",
    "ADRESS": "KEMALPAŞA MAHALLESİ ATATÜRK BULVARI 1 / EMİNÖNÜ",
    "LNG": 28.9535382991555,
    "LAT": 41.0112914996693,
    "SUBS_PRICE": 0,
    "FREE_TIME": 15
  }
```

It is ok to pull json data from the relevant link. Sending the data to the arePointsNear function and verifying true-false is ok. When I write the console.log data written in the code in the bottom line (in for), 0.index is undefined.

By the way, variables are defined independently and globally at the top.

What should I do?

Comment: Please provide an example of `data`.

Comment: I've added the arePointsNear function and sample json data

Comment: Where is `pos` defined?

Comment: It is in if that queries the current location (latlng) in user login, but globally defined as var pos

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but it's a useful tip that makes comparing a lot of distances faster: You can avoid calling Math.Sqrt() by comparing to the squared distance instead. Init `var km2 = m * m / 1000000;` and then `return dx * dx + dy * dy <= km2;`. You could probably reduce some of that math as well if you calculate dx and dy in meters instead of kilometers. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `$.each()`. Assuming you're `data` is an Array of Objects, consider this example.

```js
$(function() {
  function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, m) {
    var km = m / 1000;
    var ky = 40000 / 360;
    var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180) * ky;
    var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
    var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
  }

  var pos;
  var listStations = [];

  $.getJSON("https://example.com/json/", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, location) {
      if (arePointsNear(pos, {
          lat: location.LAT,
          lng: location.LNG
        }, 2487)) {
        listStations.push(location.ID);
      }
    });
    console.log(listStations);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the same place, the numbers [0]. [1]. keep not showing their items.

Comment: By the way, it shows in json loop, but it does not show outside of loop, unreachable data

Comment: @KadirÇolak as they were defined inside the loop callback function, they are only scoped for that. You're only adding the ID of each location to `listStations` so that's the only item accessible outside of the loop.